# React Native stuck at loading dependecy graph

Tags: react-native

Good Day, I am pretty new to react native and I ran into an issue, my metro bundler starts and gets stuck at loading dependency graph with ('...'), not moving forward or backwards

I have tried using yarn start, changing the ports although my port 8081 is free.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: any other alternatives to metro bundler?
Screenshot:[Its just stuck here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV2aR.png)

Screenshot II: [Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXewa.png)

Comment: Add a screenshot of your bundler, as well as your simulator/device at the point where you are getting stuck. More information is likely needed to answer your question.

Comment: Share your work to reproduce this.

Comment: it's a fresh project

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was my node version, was using v12, I downgraded to v10.
Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android` as well?

because `react-native start` only runs metro and usually when dependency graph is done it stays there hanging until you connect a simulator/device but it is working as expected.

You can try with `react-native --reset-cache` to clean up metro after some bad start, but in any case this only starts metro bundler. To get device running use the methods above

Comment: I did run react-native run-android, app loads with a white screen and just stays like that. Let me try react-native --reset-cache

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of `RN 0.62`, there could be two things that could be wrong.

- Make sure your node version is < `12.15` since there is a memory leak issue and you would have few issues running the bundler.
- If you are in MacOs Catalina , just go to the Security & Privacy -> files & folders in the system preferences and change the permissions for `watchman`.

The simplest way to debug this issue is running the bundler in `sudo`

```
sudo react-native start
```

And if you have permission issue with watchman then you should see bunch of errors in your console.